# Use NSUserDefaults with suiteName in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am having a problem with `NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.app-ID")`.

I try to save an `NSArray` into the `NSUserDefaults` in the container Application in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.app-ID")
defaults.setObject(["One", "Two"], forKey: "bookmarks")
defaults.synchronize()
```

In my TodayExtension I try to get the array like this:

Globaly Defenition in Extension ViewController:

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.app-ID")
var defaultsArray: NSArray!
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
defaultsArray = defaults.objectForKey("bookmarks") as NSArray
```

But `defaultsArray` always is `nil`.

The App Groups Entitlement has been added to all Targets.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint and see what are included in defaults?

Comment: It looks like `defaults` is empty: `Printing description of self.defaults:
<NSUserDefaults: 0x61800005fbf0>
Printing description of *(self.defaults):
(NSUserDefaults) [0] = {}`

Comment: Can you log the return value of `synchronize` ?

Comment: Also, have you tried getting the `NSUserDefaults` using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` ?

Comment: Same problem. I am now setting the array in the TodayExtension with `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`. Have you ever successfully used `NSUserDefaults` in a TodayExtension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your suite, but with the fact that you are trying to store a swift array as an NSObject. The following works in Playground and demonstrates how to do this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(["One", "Two"] as NSArray, forKey: "array")
let myArray = defaults.objectForKey("array") as [String] // ["One", "Two"]
```

But you can also store a Swift array. You have to use a different accessor, though.

```
defaults.setObject(["One", "Two"], forKey: "array")
let myArray = defaults.arrayForKey("array") as [String] // ["One", "Two"]
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me to add as NSArray after the Array and as [String]. this was the issue:)